# DVB Headers on Mac

Tags: header, porting, macports, television, dvb

I was trying to install some DVB tv software for Linux on Mac OS X.
I have some TV tuners and they work so much better on Linux Ubuntu than on Mac OS X with The Tube application.
There are no ports on MacPorts or Homebrew and I tried installing w_scan but it requires the Linux DVB Headers to be installed.
Is there a way to build and install them?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You just can't. The linux headers are to access features of the Linux kernel, which are obviously missing in macos.

Comment: And can I port the drivers in some way?

Comment: @AndreaBR My guess is no, unless either you are a MacOS system programmer and a Linux system programmer, or you are ready to invest a few months (years ?) of your life full time to become both.

Comment: Yes of course it can be done, if you are willing to invest most of your remaining life time and completely commit your life and that of your children and grandchildren to port the required parts of the linux kernel to MacOS. Give or take one generation. Why are people on SO always so negative?